# Numpy addition is modulo

Tags: python, numpy

I've noticed that when doing numpy addition the result is modulo.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.uint8(250)
b = np.uint8(10)
print(a + b) # prints 4
```

Is there a mathematical, computer science or functional reason behind way it is handled in this manner?

Comment: Why shouldn't it?

Comment: We don't like to speculate here. The correct people to ask about a design decision in someone else's code are **the people who wrote the code** - for example, by looking in the documentation, or asking on an issue tracker (or searching through an issue tracker). Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: See for example https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6753.

Comment: You forgot to show the Runtime warning!  I'm not an expert in this, but I believe this approach to overflow occurs at very low levels, in the underlying C or even processor math.    The linked `issues` threads talk about the processor returning an overflow flag (along with the value).

Comment: Looks like modulo for unsigned integers is part of the C standard. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Methods_to_address_integer_overflow_problems

Comment: @ScottHunter, it's not a question of should it or shouldn't it. What is the reason for handling it in such a way? Is there a mathematical or functional reason behind it.

Comment: @hpaulj correct. ```RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in ubyte_scalars```

Comment: This is a valid question, I wonder why this was closed so quickly.

Comment: @BastianVenthur Quite simply, because originally the question asked _"Why is numpy addition modulo?"_ and _"Why was numpy designed to return the modulo"_, which - by the site rules - is asking for opinions, and thus off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is the datatype `uint8` you chose, which ranges only from [0..255]. You need to pick a "bigger" type, to get the correct result.

Comment: This does not understand the question. The question is not "how do I ensure there is adequate room for the sum?", but about the *design decision* that was made to respond to the insufficient room with modulo arithmetic rather than saturation arithmetic.